# EntityManager in LoginFormAuthenticator with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I'm following the official documentation for the Authentication and Login Form. I have hard times to understand one thing: how the entityManager is transmitted to the LoginFormAuthenticator.php. 
And my problem is that I need to change this entity manager because I have two databases and my users are not on the default one. Usually, I can notify which database connexion to use in the entity manager and the repository Since I don't understand how the LoginFormAuthenticator.php gets the entity manager, I don't know where to change the database.

It is the file generated by the php bin/console make:auth command. 
LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\Common\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager =  $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'matricule' => $request->request->get('matricule'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['matricule']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class, 'common')->findOneBy(['matricule' => $credentials['matricule']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Matricule could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('fichsynth_new'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            common: 
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_COMMON_URL)%'

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            common:
                connection: common
                mappings:
                    Common:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Common'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Common'
                        alias: Common
```

I've change the getRepository(User::class, 'common') but since the entityManager is not on 'common' database connexion but 'default' one I get this error :

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'fichesynthese.utilisateur' n'existe pas
```

My User entity in in the file Entity\Common\User.php and I've already made a UserController.php where I have able to show all users from this other database. 
Thanks !

EDIT : services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator:
        arguments:
            - '@common'
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    #LISTENER DOCTRINE#
```

Comment: I've seen that there is an option called 'manager_name' in the providers section in security.yaml. I've put it to common (name of the entity_managers) but still got the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my problem by using the UserProvider object. Here is what I've used for documentations : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html
So I created the UserRepository.php file :

```
<?php 

namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    // ...

    public function loadUserByUsername($userMatricule)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.matricule = :query')
            ->setParameter('query', $userMatricule)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Then I changed the getUser() function from LoginFormAuthenticator.php :

```
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }
        dump($userProvider);
        //$user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['matricule' => $credentials['matricule']]);
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['matricule']);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Matricule could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

The commented line is the one generated by symfony4 make:auth command. If I do a dump($user) I get the correct user. In the security.yaml the manager_entity was for the UserProvider object not the entity manager, it confused me.

Then problem solved ! Thanks @Nikita Leshchev for his help, I understand new things too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly define service's config in `services.yaml`. Like this:

```
services:
  App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator:
    arguments:
      - '@your_entity_manager_service'
      ... other args
```

And then indicate this `login_form_auth` service in the `authenticators` section of your security config. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#generating-the-login-form

Like this:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
  # ...

  firewalls:
    main:
      # ...
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - 'App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The config.yaml doesn't exist. I tried to create a new one or to add this service definition in the service.yaml file. I have an error telling me ```The service "security.authentication.provider.guard.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "@login_form_auth" ```

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake, it has to be `services.yaml` instead of `config.yaml`

Comment: I thought of it but I still got the same error : ```The service "security.authentication.provider.guard.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "@login_form_auth"```

Comment: Ok then revert your security changes and change implementation in `services.yaml` to the code above (I've edited the answer)

Comment: Still no luck... I don't have the error about non-existent service but it does not go to the good database. Driving me crazy...

Comment: Looks like this Authenticator service is not created from config in process of container initialization. Can you please add `config/services.yaml` contents to the post?

Comment: I've edited the original post. I've tried ```@common, @doctrine.orm.common``` and also to specify ```entityManager: @common``` etc.. All combinations I could think of and none worked.

Comment: Do you see the `@login_form_auth` service in the output of `bin/console 
debug:container`

Comment: I see App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator which is the new name with your latest solution I guess. Running the command, I've seen a doctrine.orm.common_entity_manager so I tried to put it in the service arguments with no more luck.

Comment: Looking on an other forum for help, someone told me to use the UserProvider object instead of the entity manager. In fact, when I did a dump of the UserPRovider object I've seen that it is correctly connected to the database. So the manager name seems to set the database name for the UserProvider and not the entityManager (which by re-reading the security file seems logic). Now I have to look at how to use this UserProvider object with the database.